# watch rootScope variable to change the progressBar value

Tags: angularjs

```
app.controller("ListController1", ['$rootScope',function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.progressBar=10; 
  $rootScope.$watch(
    function() { 
      return $rootScope.progressBar; 
    },
    function(){
      alert($rootScope.progressBar);
      alert("changed");
  },true)

}]);

app.controller("ListController2", ['$scope','$rootScope',function($scope,$rootScope) {
  $scope.save=function() {
    $rootScope.progressBar=20;
  }
}]);
```

I want progressBar value form ListController2 to be reflected back in Listcontroller1. It seems i am doing something wrong with it. Please help any one. thank u.

Comment: Create a service to share the value instead of attaching it to $rootScope.

Comment: i dont have  2 controller, there are 12 controller and when the shared value in each controller changes it should be reflected in controller one and through watch so that the view canbe updated

Comment: A service is still the best way to do this. Avoid `$rootScope` - if you have to touch that it usually means you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than sharing state with `$routeScope`, you should consider creating a service to share the state of the progress bar - this is one of the use cases of services.

When the save button is pressed in the code below, it updates the value in `progressService`. The value from `progressService` is watched in the first controller and the view is updated accordingly.

You can add `progressService` to as many controllers as you'd like.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.factory("progressService", [function() {
  var service = this;
  service.progressBar = 0;
  
  return service;
}]);

app.controller("ListController1", ["$scope", "progressService", function($scope, progressService) {
  progressService.progressBar=10;
  
  $scope.progress = progressService.progressBar;
  
  $scope.$watch(
    function() { 
      return progressService.progressBar; 
    },
    function(newValue) {
      $scope.progress = newValue;
    });
}]);

app.controller("ListController2", ['$scope','progressService',function($scope,progressService) {
  $scope.save=function() {
    progressService.progressBar=20;
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="ListController1">
    Progress: {{progress}}
  </div>

  <div ng-controller="ListController2">
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
  </div>

</div>
```